# How can I do a nested search on elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I am having troubles constructing a search query in ES 7.4

Here is my mapping:

```
    [
            'settings' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 1,
                'number_of_replicas' => 1,
                'analysis' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'filter_stemmer' => [
                            'type' => 'stemmer',
                            'language' => 'english'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'g_analyzer' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'filter' => ['lowercase', 'stemmer'],
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard'
                        ],
                        "no_stopwords" => [
                            "type" => "standard",
                            "stopwords" => []
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'mappings' => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer'
                    ],
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        "analyzer" => "g_analyzer",
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        "analyzer" => "g_analyzer",
                    ],
                    'jobStatus' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'videoId' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ],
                    'thumbnail' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'playlistId' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'channelId' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'publishedDate' => [ 
                        "type" => "date",
                    ],
                    'created_at' => [ //date video was updated
                        "type" => "date",
                    ],
                    'updated_at' => [ //date video was updated
                        "type" => "date",
                    ],
                    'url' => [
                        'type' => 'text'
                    ],
                    'subtitles' => [
                        'type' => 'nested',
                        'properties' => [
                            'id' => [
                                'type' => 'integer'
                            ],
                            'start_time' => [
                                'type' => 'float'
                            ],
                            'end_time' => [
                                'type' => 'float'
                            ],
                            'text' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                "analyzer" => "g_analyzer",
                            ],
                            'langcode' => [
                                'type' => 'text'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]

                ]
            ]
        ];
```

What query do I need to search for the text "bill gates" in the subtitles, and return the subtitle "bill gates" was found in, as well as the subtitle above and below the hit?

Comment: can you add sample doc and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

As of now I am not having your sample docs and expected docs so can't try it local and provide you complete query but as you are using [nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), you need to make use of [nested queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Nested queries are used to query the nested datatype and same official doc as some examples as well, see if you can follow them, and provide what you try and from there we can help you.

Comment: I was able to create a nested query using the link you provided https://gist.github.com/firecentaur/61b618a4ebbf89a8ef199c40bcf06522  and it found 10 hits. For each hit, it included all of the subtitles in its _source.  The problem is, it doesnt tell me WHICH subtitle that the hit was found in.  Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do the nested query:

```
$body = [
        'query' => [
            'nested' => [
                'inner_hits'=>[
                    'size'=>3
                ],
                'path' => 'subtitles',
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                         'must'=>[
                             [
                                 'match'=>[ 'subtitles.text'=>$searchTerm ]
                             ]
                         ]
                    ]

                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

Doing this will add an inner hits with the subtitles with the actual found terms